# carrierwave watermark an image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, watermark

Having inside my uploader:

```
version :profile do
    process :resize_to_fill => [300, 300]
    process :quality => 90
    process :watermark
  end
```

then :

```
  def watermark
    manipulate! do |img|
      logo = Magick::Image.read("#{Rails.root}/assets/images/watermarks/watermark.png").first
      img = img.composite(logo, Magick::SouthEastGravity, Magick::OverCompositeOp)
    end
  end
```

- above won't work while imagemagick is installed
- there is no error logging so very very hard to debug
- is there a way to debug and fix above code to make a working watermark method for carrierwave?

Comment: The path to your image looks wrong - assets are normally in app/assets

Comment: can you please post the answer for us

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where's the line where you write the result to disk?

I believe the `composite` method itself doesn't write the result to disk. You have to call `img.write('composite.gif')` (or whatever filename you want) in order to actually save the result of the composite.

I suppose it's possible that carrierwave does this for you, but can you verify that by checking the output contents of the file and/or timestamps to see if the file was modified after upload?

Ref: http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/src_over.html - about half way down the page